# Вопрос по CSG-алгоритмам (бесплатные)?

Tags: алгоритм, библиотеки, 3d

Копался в интернете, хотел найти нормальные библиотеки по этому алгоритму. Нашел несколько, но они не бесплатны, написаны на С++ ((

Заинтересовала одна на JavaScript - csg.js, но работаю на C#.

Что вы посоветуете, переводить эту csg.js на С# и дорабатывать, или же есть где вариант найти бесплатную и нормальную?

Comment: Приведите название платной библиотеки, которая Вас устраивает.

Comment: http://www.geometros.com/index.htm     sgCore, в принципе меня почти устраивает, но хочется что-нибудь по-проще, открытый код, чтобы можно было управлять С# wrapper только для коммерческой версии и т.п.     http://www.opencsg.org/    OpenCSG, но там GPL лицензия, не хочу быть зависимым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ - sgCore or Opencsg